# Getiing a list [1,1,2,2,..] and add it to a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, list

I want to have a one-liner code using list comprehension which prints this sequence for an arbitrary `n`:

```py
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, ..., n, n]
```

Comment: Do you need `df['col'] = L` ?

Comment: yes. L will [1,1,2,2,3,3,...] till df.shape[0]

Comment: Are you looking for `[k//2 for k in range(2, 2*(n+1))]`? to generate the list you want?

Comment: Does "till n" mean until the final two elements are n or the list is of length n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
n = 10
result = [i//2 + 1 for i in range(n*2)]
print(result)
```

This code uses list comprehension: the `range(n*2)` function generates a range of numbers from 0 to n*2-1 and `i//2 + 1` gives the index of the pair of numbers that contains the current number, `i`.

Comment: Clever mathematical trick, but the explanation is not quite right, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

```py
[e for l in [[x]*2 for x in range(1, 10)] for e in l]
```

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Could be read as follows :
`element` for each `list` in `list of list`
as we know `list of list` is `[[x]*2 for x in range(1, 10)]`

```py
>>> [[x]*2 for x in range(1, 10)]
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]]
```

In definitive, another way to flatten a 2-levels list in one line without using for instance tools like `numpy.ndarray.flatten` or `numpy.ravel`

**Modified by Accdias** (reduction of `for` loops and then time consumption) :

```
[n for i in range(1, 10) for n in [i] * 2]
```

Indeed excellent, because uses the property of created elements which are lists and then could be iterated in the run process :

- creation of the list-like little unit `[i] * 2`
- iteration over the creation with the nearest `for` loop
- and flatten process ends with the last `for` loop

Comment: Based on OP expected result, this seems the simplest and best solution. It can be improved as `[n for i in range(1, 10) for a in [i] * 2]` or even `[n for i in range(1, 10) for a in (i, i)]`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the two propositions will each generate an exception. fact is ```n``` is not defined by the way your lists comps are written.

Comment: That was clearly a typo. Here is what I meant them to be: `[n for i in range(1, 10) for n in [i] * 2]`  and `[n for i in range(1, 10) for n in (i, i)]`.

Answer (score 1):

**If need append new column to existing DataFrame:**

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with filtering for assign even or odd number of rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4)})

n = df.shape[0]
df['new'] = np.repeat(np.arange(1, n // 2 + 2), 2)[:n]
print (df)
     a  new
0    0    1
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    2
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5)})

n = df.shape[0]
df['new'] = np.repeat(np.arange(1, n // 2 + 2), 2)[:n]
print (df)
   a  new
0  0    1
1  1    1
2  2    2
3  3    2
4  4    3
```

If always even number of rows, solution is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(8)})

df['new'] = np.repeat(np.arange(1, df.shape[0] // 2 + 1), 2) 
print (df)
   a  new
0  0    1
1  1    1
2  2    2
3  3    2
4  4    3
5  5    3
6  6    4
7  7    4
```